# How to get multiple Java objects from the same JSON file with GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

My json file looks like this:

```
{
"card":[

    {
        "id": 1,
        "CardType":"xxx",
        "CardDescription":"xxx",
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "CardType":"yyy",
        "CardDescription":"yyy",
    }
]
}
```

For each of those "cards" I'd like to generate a Java object. So I created a "Card" class in Java:

```
public class Card {
  private int id;
  private String cardType;
  private String cardDesc;

 //getters and setters
}
```

Here is my first question: How do I tell my program that "cardType" corresponds to the "CardType" in the JSON file?

My code to generate the objects so far is this:
(selectedFile is the JSON file, the user can select it with a FileChooser)

```
try{
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectedFile)); 
        JsonStreamParser p = new JsonStreamParser(reader);

        while(p.hasNext()){
            JsonElement e = p.next();
            if(e.isJsonObject()){
                Card card = gson.fromJson(e, Card.class);
                System.out.println(card.getCardDesc());
            }
        }

        //System.out.println();

    }
    catch(Exception f){
        f.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, this does not work. Error message:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unexpected value at
>   line 10 column 5 path $

Is my code wrong? Or is there a problem with my JSON file?

Comment: Claims that JSON input is *malformed* don't happen magically. It's not unheard of for a parser to be wrong, but you shouldn't assume so. What is your file *really* like, at least up to line 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parse directly to your `Card` class instead of reading over parser.

Create a wrapper:

```
public class CardArray {
    List<Card> card;
}
```

Then tell you want to map `cardType` with `CardType` path:

```
public class Card {
  private int id;
  @SerializedName("CardType") 
  private String cardType;
  @SerializedName("CardDescription") 
  private String cardDesc;

 //getters and setters
}
```

Then read your data:

```
 CardArray cardArray = gson.fromJson(reader, CardArray.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can do the work

```
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class);
gson.fromJson(jsonObject.get("card"), new TypeToken<List<Card>>(){}.getType());
```